# Using ng-if to select second item in an ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a page that loops through a bunch of content and orders/groups them out by day. The grouping works, but I want to treat the first two items in the loop differently from the rest of them. I've tried utilizing `ng-if` in the code example below using `ng-if="$first || $index == 1"` and `ng-if="!$first || !$index != 1"` but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

What is the proper way to select the first and second items in an `ng-repeat` loop?

```
<div class="col-sm-12 day-block" ng-repeat="(key,value) in article.items | groupBy:'posted|date: MMM:dd' | toArray:true ">
  <div class="col-sm-2 timestamp">
    <h3>March 9</h3>
    <h1>Day 4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10" ng-repeat="article in value | orderBy:'posted' | unique: 'nid'">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6" ng-if="$first || $index == 1">
            <span ng-class="blog-post-thumbnail" ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.main_image)"></span>
            <h2 ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.node_title)"></h2>
            <h4 ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.author)"></h4>
            <h4 ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.posted)"></h4>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="row" ng-if="!$first || $index != 1">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <span ng-class="blog-post-thumbnail" ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.main_image)"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h3 ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.node_title)"></h3>
          <h4 ng-bind-html="to_trusted(article.author)"></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want first ans second _arcticle_? or _value_?

Comment: @Grundy The first and second article in the loop

Comment: Try `ng-if="!$first || $index != 1"`

Comment: @nikunj2512 Still doesn't do it. I'll update the example with that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `ng-if="!$first || !$index == 1` will be true for all the index other then 1. 
in order to select `1st` and `2nd` you can try: `ng-if="$index == 0 || $index == 1"`

For others you can try `ng-if="!($index == 0 || $index == 1)"`

Comment: That did the trick. I had to modify it to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: I updated the answer . an upvote would have been encouraging though :p